# Overloading new/delete operators on ubuntu 22.04, libc 2.35 and calling SDL2 SDL_CreateRenderer causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, libc, ubuntu-22.04

I have my own memory manager in linux (ubuntu) in order to detect memory leaks or memory corruption in my c/c++ code.

To use my own memory manager just I've overloaded new/delete global operators like that,

```
void *operator new (size_t _size){
      return malloc(_size);
}

void operator delete(void *_pointer){
   free(_pointer);
}
```

*Code 1.1*

But in order to add some pointer information, I reserve additional memory for header metadata, for instance, to save allocator type and allocated size in this struct,

```
typedef struct{
    size_t size;
   ALLOCATOR_TYPE allocator_type
}PointerHeaderInformation;
```

where ALLOCATOR_TYPE is,

```
typedef enum{
    UNKNOWN_ALLOCATOR=0,
    NEW_ALLOCATOR,
    NEW_ALLOCATOR_WITH_BRACETS,
    MAX_ALLOCATE_TYPES
}ALLOCATOR_TYPE;
```

*Code 1.2*

So I have modified new operator seen on code 1.1 to allocate pointer and setup header information as we can see in the following code,

```
void *operator new(size_t _size){
    // set size for request _size and header information
    size_t size=sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation)+_size;
    
    // here the pointer allocation
    char *pointer=(char *)malloc(size);
    if(pointer==NULL){
       throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
    // setup header information
    ((HeaderPointerInformation *)(pointer))->type_allocator=NEW_ALLOCATOR;
    ((HeaderPointerInformation *)(pointer))->size=_size;

    // returns the pointer + sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation)
    return pointer+sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation);
}
```

*Code 1.3*

As we see at code 1.3, the it returns the pointer allocated + sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation) to not overwrite header information.

On the other side, when we want to free allocated pointer using our custom allocator, it has to get the header pointer first, check the type of allocator and free the pointer using `free` function. For instance for overloaded `delete` operator,

```
void  operator  delete(void  *pointer) noexcept{

    // check NULL
    if(pointer == NULL){
        return;
    }

    // get header information
    HeaderPointerInformation *header=(HeaderPointerInformation *)((char *)pointer-SIZEOF_ALIGNED_HEADER);

    // check type allocator
    if(header->type_allocator != NEW_ALLOCATOR){
        fprintf(stderr,"pointer was not allocated as 'new' allocator\n");
    }

    // header is the base of allocated pointer so it's freed
    free(header);
}
```

*Code 1.4*

I experimenting an extrange segmentation fault that it happens in combination with SDL2 and my overloaded new/delete operators when I try to create a renderer using SDL_CreateRenderer. SDL_CreateRenderer performs a series of calls until **last known line 70 dl-init.c before the segmentation fault in llvm::Regex::Regex() happens** as we can see in the following image.

[image]

I have never had any problems with previous ubuntu distributions, 22.04, 18.04, etc. but in the recent ubuntu distribution 22.04, which it comes with libc 2.35, so something was changed in the libc.

This segmentation fault it has to do with the overloaded operators new/delete operators because if I not using overloaded operators the problem is gone.

I have created a very simple code that produces this segmentation fault,

```
#include    <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stddef.h>
#include    <new>
#include    <cstddef>

// type of allocators
typedef enum{
    UNKNOWN_ALLOCATE=0,
    NEW_ALLOCATOR,
    NEW_ALLOCATOR_WITH_BRACETS,
    MAX_ALLOCATE_TYPES
}ALLOCATOR_TYPE;

// metadata information included in the pointer allocated
typedef  struct{
    char    type_allocator;
    int     size;
}HeaderPointerInformation;

void *newPointer(size_t _size, ALLOCATOR_TYPE _allocator_type){
    size_t size=sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation)+_size;
    char *pointer=(char *)malloc(size);
    if(pointer==NULL){
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    ((HeaderPointerInformation *)(pointer))->type_allocator=_allocator_type;
    ((HeaderPointerInformation *)(pointer))->size=size;

    // returns the pointer base (allocated pointer with offset of metadata information)
    return pointer+sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation);
}

void*  operator  new(size_t  _size) {
    return newPointer(_size,NEW_ALLOCATOR);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void*  operator  new[](size_t  _size) {
    return  newPointer(_size,NEW_ALLOCATOR_WITH_BRACETS);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void  operator  delete(void  *pointer) noexcept{

    // return if pointer==NULL
    if(pointer == NULL){
       return;
    }

    // get header information
    HeaderPointerInformation *header=(HeaderPointerInformation *)((char *)pointer-sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation));

    // check type allocator
    if(header->type_allocator != NEW_ALLOCATOR){
        fprintf(stderr,"pointer was not allocated as 'new' allocator\n");
    }

    // header is the base of allocated pointer so it's freed
    free(header);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void  operator  delete[](void  *pointer)  noexcept{

    // return if pointer==NULL
    if(pointer == NULL){
       return;
    }

    // get header information
    HeaderPointerInformation *header=(HeaderPointerInformation *)((char *)pointer-sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation));

    // check type allocator
    if(header->type_allocator != NEW_ALLOCATOR_WITH_BRACETS){
        fprintf(stderr,"pointer was not allocated as 'new []' allocator\n");
    }

    // header is the base of allocated pointer so it's freed
    free(header);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    printf(
        "align(std::max_align_t):%i\n"
        "sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation):%i\n"
        ,(int)(alignof(std::max_align_t))
        ,(int)(sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation))
   );

    //--------------------------------------------------
    // BEGIN: test that overloaded new/delete works as expected
    int *i=new int;
    int *ii=new int[2];

    delete i;
    delete [] ii;
    // END: test that overloaded new/delete works as expected
    //--------------------------------------------------

    if (SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to init video subsystem: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("test",50,50,100,100,0);

    if (!window) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Calling SDL_CreateRenderer it causes segmentation fault at llvm::Regex::Regex
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    if (!renderer) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to create renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(renderer != NULL){
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    }

    if(window != NULL){
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    }
}
```

*Code 1.5*

As we can see in the code 1.5, first there're delete/new operator implementations, then in the main code it performs a test using overloaded operators new/delete that check its functionallity and the rest is just SDL2 initialization.

To compile just as simple as follow,

```
g++ main.cpp -Ipath_include_sdl2 -Lpath_lib_sdl2 -lSDL2 -lm -o main
```

Note: You have to provide *path_include_sdl2* and *path_lib_sdl2* if necessary

---

**Why to NOT usign address sanitizer (aka ASAN) tool that comes with gnu compiler itself as is suggested by some comments ?**

I don't know yet if I'll switch using ASAN, but in principle I won't becasue my code is also compiles on windows through mingw and AFAIK mingw ASAN is not implemented yet.

---

**Edit(s) with regard to user17732522 (comments) I have change code 1.5,**

- Fixed point 2, so on overloaded new and new[] operators I added conditional to throw sdt::bad_alloc if resulting of pointer after doing `malloc` is NULL,

```
void *newPointer(size_t _size, ALLOCATOR_TYPE _allocator_type){

    ...

    char *pointer=(char *)malloc(size);
    if(pointer==NULL){
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    ...
}
```

- Fixed point 5, so on overloaded delete and delete[] operators, it has changed `noexcept(true)` by `noexcept`,

```
    void  operator  delete(void  *pointer) noexcept{
      ...
    }
            
    void  operator  delete[](void  *pointer)  noexcept{
      ...
    }
```

- Fixed point 6, it has changed `free((void *)header)` by `free(header)`
- Fixed point 7, on overloaded function *delete* it has added conditional that returns if pointer passed is NULL

```
    void  operator  delete(void  *pointer) noexcept{
           // check NULL
           if(pointer == NULL){
               return;
           }
           ...
    }

    void  operator  delete[](void  *pointer) noexcept{
           // check NULL
           if(pointer == NULL){
               return;
           }
           ...
    }
            
    void  operator  delete[](void  *pointer)  noexcept{
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a custom new/delete instead of ASAN?

Comment: I'm not using ASAN because, overloading my new/delete operators I managed the way to track file-line in friendly way where exactly memory leak ocurrs wheres, AFAIK, ASAN it tells you that there's a memory leak but not the location (it gives some information as main+0x12845). Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: It means you build without debug info. Add `-g` to see file+line.

Comment: @HollyBlockCat You are right and thanks for the answer! I added -g and I see the symbols.  But still not sure to switch to ASAN my code compiles also in mingw that AFAIK ASAN is not implemented yet

Comment: "I have my own memory manager in linux (ubuntu) in order to detect memory leaks or memory corruption" - have you considered just using [address sanitizer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer)?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl, Yes in this context (using ubuntu or linux), I could switch to address sanitizer (aka ASAN) but I want to solve this issue just in case someone is caught in the same problem. Also, note that ASAN is not supported on other toolchains like mingw

Comment: CLANG64 [MSYS2 environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/) does have sanitizers on Windows. It doesn't have iterator debugging, so I don't use it always, but it's there if you need sanitizers.

Comment: @holyblackcat so a thing to be considered to switch "clang" toolchain on Windows :-).

Comment: Please don't add the solution to the question. Only post it as an answer. Having an "edit history" of snippets is also usually discouraged, either edit the original code or don't (don't, if you already got an answer).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've put as solution because, after the comments about the issue of unaligned memory that user 'user17732522' pointed, the segmentation fault problem was vanished. I've unchecked as a solution. Well, sorry if I've don't suited as  the Stackoverflow rules. I'm trying to do the best. The thing is that in the begin I've put a simplified code but in the time it has been modified through the comments to get the final code better.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple problems:

1. You do not make sure that the pointer you return from your `operator new` replacement is aligned at least as strictly as `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`, which this overload must always guarantee. Even if `malloc` is guaranteed to return suitably aligned memory, your offset may change the alignment of the pointer that you return. But `malloc` may also not align sufficiently. `malloc` is guaranteed to align at least to `alignof(std::max_align_t)` which may be smaller than `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`.
2. The `operator new` overload you are replacing must not return a null pointer. You need to check the result of `malloc` and if it is a null pointer you must throw `std::bad_alloc`. Because you are dereferencing the pointer inside your implementation that is even more directly important.

Less severe problems:

3. The way you access the header structure are aliasing violations. Your header structure is an implicit-lifetime type, so you don't necessarily need to `new` it explicitly, however you need to `std::launder` your pointer to access it. This would be enough for `operator new`, however I don't think there is any strictly standard-conforming way to implement the `operator delete` to be able to access the header, so I guess you need to rely on the compiler behaving "reasonably" here anyway.
4. If you replace `operator new` and `operator delete` for the overloads without alignment parameter, you probably also want to replace those with `std::align_val_t` parameter, in case the program allocates memory with alignment requirements stricter than `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`.
5. `noexcept(true)` on the deallocation functions is redundant. They are `noexcept(true)` by default. Also this is canonically written as `noexcept`, not `noexcept(true)`.
6. The `void*` cast in `free((void *)header);` is redundant. It works implicitly (and you are using that in the return statement of `operator new`).

(Edit) Additional *severe* issue:

7. The `operator delete` overloads you are replacing here must accept null pointer values as argument. Your current implementation does not since it immediately does pointer arithmetic on the pointer. You need to check for a null pointer and return from the function in that case before trying to access the header.

---

Also in context of what you are trying to do: There are already tools which provide the functionality you are trying to implement, for example ASAN and valgrind.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reponse. I've fixed some of your points (multiple problems -2- and less severe problems -5 and 6-) at code 1.4. So if I compile program the printf located at starting it prints the following,
__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__:16
sizeof(std::max_align_t):32
sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation):16

 I've never known about memory alignment. Because, the alignment issue is new for me I've to study a little more. So thanks again user17732522

Comment: @JordiEspada It is supposed to be `alignof(std::max_align_t)`, not `sizeof`. Also, please don't fix stuff mentioned in answers in the question. It makes it impossible for other readers to follow the answer. You can instead add more information after the original code in your question. Also, it would of course be nice to know whether any of this fixed your issue.

Comment: @JordiEspada I added another severe issue I noticed to the answer.

Comment: I'm not using ASAN because, overloading my new/delete operators I managed the way to track file-line in friendly way where exactly memory leak ocurrs wheres, AFAIK, ASAN it tells you that there's a memory leak but not the location (it gives some information as main+0x12845). Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @JordiEspada If you compile with debug symbols enabled and everything is setup correctly in your environment, then ASAN should resolve these addresses to full function names with file names and line numbers. It may be necessary to specify an environment variable like `ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1` (although that should be default) and/or to check that you have the `llvm-symbolizer` program installed.

Comment: You are completely right! I just tested adding flags -g -O0 and I can see file and line!! But still not sure to switch to ASAN my code compiles also in mingw that AFAIK ASAN is not implemented yet

Comment: @ user17732522 thank to your suggestions I think I solved this issue that is caused by a bad aligned returned pointer. I never thought about allocators should return aligned blocks

Answer (score 0):

As user17732522 pointed out the pointer returned it has to be correctly aligned in blocks as `alignof(std::max_align_t)` that in my machine is `16`.

In the case of overloaded operator new, after allocate pointer through `malloc` (that returns perfectly and aligned pointer) I return a pointer as pointer base with an offset of `sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation)` that in case is `8` so it **returns an unaligned pointer**.

So to solve this issue is has to calcule a valid offset transforming `sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation)` as multiple of `alignof(std::max_align_t)` like it describes the following line,

```
#define SIZEOF_ALIGNED_HEADER       (sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation)/BLOCK_ALIGNMENT+1)*BLOCK_ALIGNMENT
```

Where indeed BLOCK_ALIGMENT is defined as,

```
#define BLOCK_ALIGNMENT             alignof(std::max_align_t)
```

Finally I present the modified code 1.5 of overloaded functions returning/getting the pointer with the right offset,

```
#define BLOCK_ALIGNMENT             alignof(std::max_align_t)
#define SIZEOF_ALIGNED_HEADER       (sizeof(HeaderPointerInformation)/BLOCK_ALIGNMENT+1)*BLOCK_ALIGNMENT


void *newPointer(size_t _size, ALLOCATOR_TYPE _allocator_type){
    size_t size=SIZEOF_ALIGNED_HEADER+_size;

    char *pointer=(char *)malloc(size);

    ...

    // returns the pointer base (allocated pointer with offset of metadata information)
    return pointer+SIZEOF_ALIGNED_HEADER;
}


void  operator  delete(void  *pointer) noexcept{

    ...

    // get header information
    HeaderPointerInformation *header=(HeaderPointerInformation *)((char *)pointer-SIZEOF_ALIGNED_HEADER);

    ...
    
    // header is the base of allocated pointer so it's freed
    free(header);
}

void  operator  delete[](void  *pointer)  noexcept{

    ...

    // get header information
    HeaderPointerInformation *header=(HeaderPointerInformation *)((char *)pointer-SIZEOF_ALIGNED_HEADER);
        
    ...
    
    // header is the base of allocated pointer so it's freed
    free(header);
}
```